# Is there a way to update a Fabric distributed app within the app?

Tags: ios, testing, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

What I'd like to do is to put a button in my app (in a developer dashboard) that my testers could press on and it would check to see if they have the latest build and if not, download the latest build from Fabric/Crashlytics. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a tester launches an app distributed via Fabric Beta a check is automatically made to see if a new version is available. If there is, a notification is shown and the tester has the option to download the latest build. There isn't a mechanism that lets users check for an update manually within your app.

Comment: Does this happen only with updated versions or also with updated builds?

Comment: This happens with any new distribution you make - versions or builds.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. If this works on the next build I push, I'll mark your answer as correct :).